# Ansible hangs due to its constructed ssh issue

Tags: python, jenkins, ssh, ansible, freeze

I trigger the below ansible playbook using Jenkins pipeline.

```
- name: Play 2- Configure Source nodes
  hosts: "{{ location }}"
  user: remoteuser
  strategy: free
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_extra_args: -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectionAttempts=5
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: /app/automation/id_rsa

  tasks:
    
    - name: Execute script 
      shell: "/app/mybkp.sh"
```

The above ansible-playbook is run as below in debug mode:

```
ansible-playbook orabackup.yml_final -i ora.hosts -f 90 -e location=MYIP -e ansible_ssh_use_tty=no -vvv
```

Below is the output where the Jenkins freezes and never completes.

```
PLAY [Play 2- Configure Source nodes] ******************************************
META: ran handlers
<10.0.0.111> Attempting python interpreter discovery
<10.0.0.111> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: remoteuser
<10.0.0.111> SSH: EXEC ssh -o 'IdentityFile="/app/automation/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="remoteuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectionAttempts=5 10.0.0.111 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo PLATFORM; uname; echo FOUND; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.6'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.5'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python2.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python2.6'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/libexec/platform-python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python3'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; echo ENDFOUND && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.0.0.111> (0, 'PLATFORM
AIX
FOUND
/usr/bin/python3
ENDFOUND
', 'This system is for the use of authorized users only. Individuals using this computer system without authority, or in excess of their authority, are subject to having all of their activities on this system monitored and recorded by system personnel. In the course of monitoring individuals improperly using this system, or in the course of system maintenance, the activities of authorized users may also be monitored. Anyone using this system expressly consents to such monitoring and is advised that if such such monitoring reveals possible evidence of criminal activity, system personnel may provide the evidence of such monitoring to the law enforcement officials
')
<10.0.0.111> Python interpreter discovery fallback (unsupported platform for extended discovery: aix)
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/commands/command.py
Pipelining is enabled.
<10.0.0.111> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: remoteuser

<10.0.0.111> SSH: EXEC ssh -o 'IdentityFile="/app/automation/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="remoteuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectionAttempts=5 10.0.0.111 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python3 && sleep 0'"'"''
```

The ssh constructed by ansible as visible in Jenkins log above, when executed manually in putty terminal also freezes / hangs and never returns.

This issue does not happen with other IPs but is specific to this IP `10.0.0.111`

I removed  `'/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python3 && sleep 0'"'"''` from the ssh command, tried manually and it worked !!

I have uploaded the working `ssh` without  `'/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python3 && sleep 0'"'"''` in debug mode here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MGWpWK2IeWa_LlifixrLTCwxv1IfvH2t/view?usp=sharing

I have uploaded the failed(freezing) `ssh` with  `'/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python3 && sleep 0'"'"''` here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yXictTMKfNDqu4wqQejyt5TVM483v7s2/view?usp=sharing

The target server `10.0.0.111` is AiX 6.1.

Can you please suggest how do i resolve this issue?

Comment: Try this: `ssh ... '/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/python3 && sleep 0" </dev/null'`

Comment: @Zsigmond Lőrinczy I tried your suggestion and it did not hang which is good but it also did not connect to remote host. So the problem persists. Infact even this hangs `ssh ... '/bin/sh'` hangs !!

Comment: (Ops, I didn't meant _literally_ the three dots.)

Comment: Neither did I @ZsigmondLőrinczy :D. What hangs is `ssh -o 'IdentityFile="/app/automation/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="remoteuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectionAttempts=5 10.0.0.111 '/bin/sh'`

Comment: This doesn't hang, just waits input from the standard input. Try `... 'bin/sh </dev/null'`. Also ssh's `-T` option should be used.

Comment: Mind you, whatever you can do with ansible, you can do it without ansible, but it will be simple and straightforward, instead of confusing.

Comment: @Zsigmond Lőrinczy i tried `-T` option but the ssh still does not work. when i try with `-tt` opyion like here `ssh -o 'IdentityFile="/app/automation/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="remoteuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectionAttempts=5 -tt 10.0.0.111 '/bin/sh'` it takes me to a prompt that looks like `>>>` however, i do not know what do I do about it.

Comment: You forgot the `</dev/null` part, either locally or remotely: `ssh -T user@host 'sh </dev/null'` or `ssh -T user@host 'sh' </dev/null`

Comment: @Lorinczy Zsigmond tried all these suggestions... due to `</dev/null` it does not wait for input(does not appear hung) but it does not login either and ssh fails!!

Comment: Please start with simple things... This command "hangs": `ssh aixuser@aix 'sh'` this command doesn't "hang": `ssh aixuser@aix 'sh </dev/null'`

Comment: You are correct @LorinczyZsigmond. However ssh is not successful for both the commands

Comment: First of all, check whether ssh-connections work at all. AIX-servers tend to run twenty years old software, which might be too old for an ssh-server.

Comment: @Ashar How did you solve it? Most comments here assume you can change the command, but it is how ansible composes it!

Comment: @M4rk ansible gives us to flexibility to tweak the ssh command it constructs. In my case there was a firewall rule that restricted 20 ssh connection per minute due to which the process was blocked and thus hung

Answer (score 1):

In `ansible.cfg` set:

```
[connection]
pipelining = False
```

AIX seems to have issues https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/17826